# Image:active border not working

Tags: jquery, css

I have 5 images inline with 1px border. I want for hover and active the border to have a different color.

I used the following code

```
$('img').click(function(){ $(this).toggleClass('orangeborder'); });
```

to border my images. It works perfect. But I have 5 images and the border remain on all images on click. I want to have border only on the last image clicked. When I click on the first image to have border and when I click on the second image to have border only on the second image, not on the both images. How can I do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove the class from all images then add it to the clicked one.

```
$('img').click(function(){ 
    $('img').removeClass('orangeborder');
    $(this).addClass('orangeborder'); 
});
```

Comment: It will be a little more logical to change `toggleClass` to `addClass`.

Comment: @Regent You're absolutely right. I was a bit too fast by copy pasting the question. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Fist remove class `orangeborder` from all images and then add class `orangeborder` on specified image as shown :

```
 $('img').click(function(){ 
   $('img').removeClass('orangeborder');
   $(this).addClass('orangeborder'); 
 });
```

Comment: What is wrong with `$('img').removeClass('orangeborder');`?

Comment: @Regent..posted another way also..sometimes second approach creates problem with old jquery versions.

Comment: Interesting... At which jQuery version does `.removeClass()` for multiple elements cause problem?